# Proof of some properties about orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

$Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, how to prove.

$$\langle Qu,Qv\times Qw\rangle=\langle u,v\times w\rangle$$ for any $u,v,w$ which belong to $\mathbb R^3$

Much obliged if you can help me!

Comment: Does $\times$ mean the cross-product here?

Comment: One method is to use the formula proven [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/859836/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes ,sorry as I don't know how to use the symbol

Comment: $Q$ is just a rotation (or reflection). $\lbrace u, v\times w\rbrace$ is a volume. If you rotate all three vectors, volume doesn't change. Check for reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true as presented. The correct version is
$$
|\langle Qu,Qv\times Qw\rangle| = |\langle u,v\times w\rangle|
$$
since the two will have opposite sign if $Q$ is a reflection.

The key here is to note that both quantities give the same volume, or to show that
$$
(Qa)\times(Qb) = (\det Q)\; Q (a \times b)
$$