# An unusual cross product identity

Tags: vectors, cross-product

In [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.413.3008&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the author gives a couple of unusual vector identities involving the cross product, namely (changing the notation to be a bit more standard), if $M$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $a,b$ are three-dimensional,
$$ (Ma) \times (Mb) = (\operatorname{adj}{M})(a \times b) , \tag{1} $$
$$ b \times (Ma) - a \times (Mb) = M^T (a \times b) - (\operatorname{tr}{M})(a \times b) . \tag{2} $$
(1) is fairly well-known (and [has been asked about before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859836/221811), albeit in slightly different form). I'm interested in proofs of (2). The paper says they plugged it into Mathematica, but I'd like to see something a bit more human-readable.

I've come up with the following summation convention proof, and would be interested in seeing proofs that use vector identities, rather than summation convention.

---

We start with
$$ T = \epsilon_{pij} \epsilon_{pmn}  \epsilon_{mkl} M_{kn} a_i b_j e_l , $$
and expand the triple $\epsilon$ in two ways:
$$ \epsilon_{pij} \epsilon_{pmn}  \epsilon_{mkl} = (\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}) \epsilon_{mkl} = \epsilon_{ikl}\delta_{jn} - \epsilon_{jkl}\delta_{in} \\
= \epsilon_{pij} (\delta_{nk}\delta_{pl}-\delta_{nl}\delta_{pk}) = \epsilon_{lij}\delta_{nk} - \epsilon_{kij}\delta_{nl} , $$
which gives
$$ T = (\epsilon_{ikl}\delta_{jn} - \epsilon_{jkl}\delta_{in}) M_{kn} a_i b_j e_l \\
= \epsilon_{ikl} a_i M_{kj} b_j e_l - \epsilon_{jkl} b_j M_{ki} a_i e_l \\
= a \times (Mb) - b \times (Ma) $$
and
$$ T = (\epsilon_{lij}\delta_{nk} - \epsilon_{kij}\delta_{nl}) M_{kn} a_i b_j e_l \\
= M_{kk} \epsilon_{ijl} a_i b_j e_l - M_{kl} e_l \epsilon_{ijk} a_i b_j \\
(\operatorname{tr}{M}) (a \times b) - M^T (a \times b) $$

But I got this proof by reverse-engineering the left-hand side, and I haven't got a satisfactory vectorial interpretation of $T$. Can someone provide either a more vectory proof, or a nice interpretation for $T$ itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove an identity $x=y$ of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, it suffices to prove that
$x\cdot c=y\cdot c$ for all $c\in\Bbb R^3$. So for $(2)$, I'll prove that
$$(b \times (Ma) - a \times (Mb))\cdot c = 
(M^T (a \times b) - (\operatorname{tr}{M})(a \times b))\cdot c . \tag{2'}$$
for all vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Write
$$[a,b,c]=(a\times b)\cdot c$$
for the scalar triple product. This is a trilinear map, and is **alternating**:
$$[b,b,c]=[a,b,b]=0$$
for all $a$, $b$, $c$. There is only one alternating trilinear map up to scalar
multiplication; any alternating trilinear map is a constant multiple
of the scalar triple product.

Let $M$ be a matrix, and define
$$\phi(a,b,c)=[Ma,b,c]+[a,Mb,c]+[a,b,Mc].$$
It's easy to see that $\phi$ is alternating trilinear, so
$$\phi(a,b,c)=t[a,b,c]$$
where $t$ depends only on $M$. Taking $a$, $b$, $c$ to be the standard unit
vectors gives $t=\text{Tr}(M)$. Therefore
$$[Ma,b,c]+[a,Mb,c]+[a,b,Mc]=\text{Tr}(M)[a,b,c].\tag{3}$$

Observe that
$$[Ma,b,c]=-(b\times Ma)\cdot c,$$
$$[a,Mb,c]=(a\times Mb)\cdot c,$$
$$[a,b,Mc]=(a\times b)\cdot Nc=(M^T(a\times b))\cdot c$$
(using the identity $x\cdot My=M^Tx\cdot y$)
and
$$\text{Tr}(M)[a,b,c]=(\text{Tr}(M)(a\times b))\cdot c.$$
So $(3)$ becomes
$$(-b\times Ma+a\times Mb+M^T(a\times b))\cdot c=\text{Tr}(M)(a\times b)\cdot c$$
which is equivalent to $(2')$.

Comment: This is a nice way to think about it. I admit the lack of symmetry rather stumped me. Not surprising I couldn't find a nice interpretation for $T$, since this viewpoint suggests it's essentially incomplete.

Comment: This also has some nice generalisations,
$$ [Ma,Mb,c] + [Ma,b,Mc]+[a,Mb,Mc] = (\text{coeff of } t \text{ in } \det{(M-tI)}) [a,b,c] ,$$
the well-known
$$ [Ma,Mb,Mc] = (\det{M}) [a,b,c] , $$
and similarly for $[Ma,Nb,Nc]+[Na,Mb,Nc]+[Na,Nb,Mc]$ being the coefficient of $t$ in the generalised characteristic polynomial $\det{(M-Nt)}$. There's also
$$ [Ma,Nb,Pc]+(\text{permutations of }M,N,P) = \lambda [a,b,c] , $$
where it seems $\lambda = \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmn} A_{il}B_{jm}C_{kn}$, which I doubt has a nice matrix expression!

Comment: @Chappers Indeed. All of this really comes out of the exterior algebra.