# Proving the cross product matrix tranformation identity with an alternative solution

Tags: matrices, transformation

I'm solving a problem from the book, *Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics, Third Edition*, by Eric Lengley. The problem goes:

> Let $N$ be the normal vector to a surface at a point $P$, and let $S$ and $T$ be tangent vectors at the point $P$ such that $S \times T = N$. Given an invertible 3 $\times$ 3 matrix $M$, show that $(MS) \times (MT) = (\text{det}M(M^{-1})^{T}(S \times T)$, supporting the fact that normals are correctly transformed by the inverse transpose of the matrix $M$.

The author provided a hint stating we can represent $(MS) \times (MT)$ as

$$
(MS) \times (MT) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -(MS)_{z} & (MS)_{y} \\ 
(MS)_{z} & 0 & -(MS)_{x} \\ 
-(MS)_{y} & (MS)_{x} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
MT
$$

We then find a matrix $G$ such that

$$
GU
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -(MS)_{z} & (MS)_{y} \\ 
(MS)_{z} & 0 & -(MS)_{x} \\ 
-(MS)_{y} & (MS)_{x} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
M
$$

where

$$
U =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -S_{z} & S_{y} \\ 
S_{z} & 0 & -S_{x} \\ 
-S_{y} & S_{x} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and show that $G = (\text{det}M)(M^{-1})^{T}$ to solve the problem.

I am aware that there is an [alternative solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860601/561643) to this problem, but I would like to solve it through the hints provided. Unfortunately, I am only able to go as far doing:

$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -(MS)_{z} & (MS)_{y} \\ 
(MS)_{z} & 0 & -(MS)_{x} \\ 
-(MS)_{y} & (MS)_{x} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
M
U^{-1}
$$

At this point, I do not know how to proceed with showing that $G = (\text{det}M)(M^{-1})^{T}$. How would you proceed? I'd like to ask for hints on solving the problem.

Comment: Your work so far is flawed in that $U$ is not an invertible matrix

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense to "show" that $G$ has the given form since the equation $GU = (MS)_{\times}M$ does not have a unique solution

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the author was hinting at; it might be helpful if you could write exactly what the author said.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I updated the question to include more of what the author hinted at, but still removed the portions that reference another part of the book to keep the question as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [scalar-triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product): we know that
$$
A \cdot (B \times C) = \det[A \ \ B\ \ C],
$$
where $A \cdot B = A^TB$ denotes a dot-product (and ${}^T$ denotes a transpose).
With that, we can deduce the entries of $(MS) \times (MT)$.

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ denote the $x,y,z$ unit vectors. Using the above and the rule $\det(PQ) = \det(P)\det(Q)$, we see that for all $i$,
$$
\begin{align}
(Me_i) \cdot [(MS) \times (MT)] & = \det[Me_i \ \ MS\ \ MT] \\
& = \det(M) \det[e_i\ \ S\ \ T] \\
& = \det(M) (e_i \cdot (S\times T)) \\
& = \det(M) (S\times T)_i.
\end{align}
$$
That is, we have
$$
\begin{align}
M^T ((MS) \times (MT)) & = \pmatrix{(Me_1)^T\\ (Me_2)^T\\ (Me_3)^T}((MS) \times (MT)) \\
& = \det(M)\pmatrix{(S \times T)_1\\ (S \times T)_2 \\ (S \times T)_3} \\
& = \det(M) (S \times T).
\end{align}
$$
Solving for $S \times T$, we have
$$
M^T ((MS) \times (MT)) = \det(M) (S \times T) \implies 
(MS) \times (MT) = \det(M)M^{-T} (S \times T),
$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: Having written this out, I see that this is essentially the same as [Omran's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/859859/81360) form the linked post. That said, I'm leaving this up with the hope that it is more easily understandable to some, since it is framed in a more elementary/directly computational fashion.

Comment: I actually prefer this over Omran's proof since this is more understandable for me.

Comment: We're using $M_{e_{i}}$ here since it equivalent to $(MS) \times (MT)$ and would give us more fluidity in solving the problem, right?

Comment: $M e_i$ is meant to denote the product of the matrix $M$ with the column $e_1$. For example, 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&9&10} \implies Me_1 = \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&9&10}  \pmatrix{1\\0\\0} = \pmatrix{1\\4\\7}.
$$
Note that $Me_i$ is the $i$th column of $M$.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais So I'm not quite sure what you were trying to say in your comment but I suspect that it is wrong.

Comment: Ah. I see. I think I understand the proof better. We got $M^{T}$ (and $Me_{i}$ as a result) to multiply with $(MS) \times (MT)$ since:

$$
(MS) \times (MT) = (\text{det}M)(M^{-T})(S \times T) \implies M^{T}((MS) \times (MT)) = (\text{det}M)(S \times T)
$$

Comment: You keep writing $M_{e_i}$ instead of $M e_i$ and I don't understand why

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyways, I updated the comment I prematurely entered by accident. Thanks for the help, by the way!

Comment: No problem ${}{}$