# Prove $\mathbf b\times(\mathbf aM)-\mathbf a\times(\mathbf bM)=(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)M-(\mathrm{tr}M) (\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product

I want to prove the following identity:
For $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in \mathbb R^3, M\in M_3(\mathbb R)$, we have
$$\mathbf b\times(\mathbf aM)-\mathbf a\times(\mathbf bM)=(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)M-(\mathrm{tr} M )(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)$$

One direct way to prove it is to write out the components of $\mathbf a,\mathbf b$ and $M$, then compare the result of $LHS$ and $RHS$ by brute force, but this way seems not so beautiful. Is there any nice (elegant) way to prove this identity? I guess probably there's a geometric interpretation of this identity.

Comment: What is $M$? What is $a\times b$? If it is the cross product, then what is $M(a\times b)$? A vector? But then it cannot have a trace?

Comment: There is still an issue with $(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)M-(\mathrm{tr} M)(\mathbf a\times\mathbf b)$ as the first term is a matrix but the second one is a scalar.

Comment: I have just edited the question, now it is clear.

Comment: It might be useful to note that we can rewrite the left hand side as 
$$
(\mathbf{b-a} )\times (\mathbf aM) + \mathbf a \times (\mathbf a M - \mathbf b M). 
$$

Comment: Also, from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748536/81360), we have
$$
(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b)M = \det(M)(\mathbf a M^{-T}) \times (\mathbf b M^{-T})
$$

Answer (score 2):

The proposed identity may be written as
$$(\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{ml} -\epsilon_{imk}\delta_{lj} -\epsilon_{lmj}\delta_{ki} +\epsilon_{imj}\delta_{lk})a_mb_jM_{lk}=0$$
where the expression in brackets is *almost* one of the identities listed in equations (5)-(9) in "The Isotropic Invariants of Fifth-rank Cartesian Tensors", Int. J. Quantum Chem. vol V 381-386 (1971).

Is the author of the question certain the first term on the right hand side of their identity is not $M \cdot ({\bf a}\times{\bf b})$, rather than $({\bf a}\times{\bf b})\cdot M$? (Assuming $M$ is not symmetric.) If it were, then the third term in the brackets would be $\epsilon_{kmj}\delta_{li}$, which yields a more symmetric result, and the expression in the brackets does vanish!